# Least selling products

Tags: products, query, magento-1.7

I am kinda new in Magento and I have been searching for the query over the internet for the passed few days regarding the "**Least selling products**" in Magento or a list of products that are not sold or at least have the fewest quantity sold and i have not been that lucky enough to find one.

**My first attempt** was just to **reverse the query from best selling products** (`sales_flat_order_item`) but the problem is that I would only be getting a list products that are sold with the least quantity not the products which were not sold or 0 quantity sold.

Can anyone at least give me some an idea or tips on how to start this one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$unsold = array();
foreach ($catalog as $product) {
    $sales = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
    $sales->addFieldToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $product->getId());
    if (!$sales->getSize()) {
       $unsold[] = $product->getId();
    }
}

// Product ids of products that haven't been sold
Zend_Debug::dump($unsold);
```

I think this should work! Untested, so give it a shot. You can filter the product collection how you like (disabled, enabled, etc).  There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but if you're just running a report every so often, it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: hi i just have another question regarding your answer, what is this !$sales->getSize() referring to? and what if Im wanted to translate that line to a simple query? @pspahn

Comment: `getSize()` basically checks the count on a Magento collection. As we loop through each product, we check the `sales/order_item` collection for entries corresponding to each product ID. If none are found (ie. `!$sales->getSize()`) then we store that product ID in an array we can use later. I am not sure what you mean by "translate that line to a simple query".

Comment: Now I get it. What i was trying to say earlier ("translate that line to a simple query") is I was converting your answer to a Query and here is it what I got: 
select * from catalog_product_entity A where 
  ( select count(*) from sales_flat_order_item B where A.entity_id = B.product_id)
But I was having a different result with your provided solution:
My query result is:
3
4
10
12
19
And the result from your solution was:
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 13
    [6] => 17
    [7] => 18
    [8] => 20
    [9] => 21
different result different ids @pspahn

Comment: can you please confirm whether my query is correct? Thank you very much @pspahn

Comment: this has already been resolved. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP! :-)

Answer (score 1):

another approach is to hang this off the sales reports, bearing in mind that your statistics for the reports need to be up to date.

```
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $daysBack = 1;
        $customCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter(
                        'visibility',
                        array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                           Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG)
                );
         $customCollection->addOrderedQty(
                        $this->getDateBack($daysBack), $this->getTodayDate()
                    );
$customCollection->getSelect()->order(
                    'ordered_qty ' . Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC
                );
                $customCollection->getSelect()->order(
                    'order_items_name ' . Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC
                );
```

And the two methods used for days calculation:

```
protected function getDateBack($value)
    {
        return $dateBack = date(
            'Y-m-j G:i:s',
            strtotime('-' . $value . ' day' . $this->getTodayDate())
        );
    }

    protected function getTodayDate()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(
            Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT
        );
    }
```

So, you easily flip that for best selling ;)

```
$customCollection->getSelect()->order(
                        'ordered_qty ' . Zend_Db_Select::SQL_DESC
```

or go for least/best viewed products, if you want, by simply chnaging what gets ordered

```
$customCollection->getSelect()->order(
                    'views ' . Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC
                );
                $customCollection->getSelect()->order(
                    'entity_id ' . Zend_Db_Select::SQL_DESC
                );
```

Note: this code was extracted from my [Dynamic Category Products](http://www.proxiblue.com.au/magento-dynamic-category-products.html) Extension, so untested standalone as given, but it will give the idea.